# VBA IE.Document empty error

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, document

I've been running a query for a while now getting data from a webpage.  After numerous runs it has decided to stop working, and I've traced the issue back to the ie.document object - it never returns anything.

When compiling my project I see that the "Document" element of ie returns an error of "Applicaiton-defined or Object-defined error" - even before I navigate to a webpage.  Also some other elements return this error also - namely "Status Text" and "Type"

The link contains a screenshot of my error:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wcxxep8my10nu8h/vba%20ie%20document.jpg?dl=0

In case that doesn't work here a scaled back version of the code I'm running

```
Sub getCard()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim url1 As String

    url1 = "google.com"

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate url1
    WaitBrowserQuiet ie

End Sub

Sub WaitBrowserQuiet(objIE As InternetExplorer)

Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

End Sub
```

As soon as I get to the "Set ie = New InternetExplorer" part of the code is when the ie object is created and I see the errors.  If I do happen to navigate to webpage, then the ie.document object is empty.

I've searched around and tried a few things to stop this happening - restarted my computer, run "ie.quit" and "Set ie = Nothing", reset my Internet Explorer, etc...  Nothing seems to work.

It seems like it may be a deeper issue given I'm getting an error message even before navigating to a webpage.  Hope someone knows how to stop the error.

Comment: What happens with **early binding** ? e.g. `Dim ie As New InternetExplorer` and remove the `Set ie = ...`

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error - the ie object now becomes visible upon running the " ie.Visible = True" line and the errors are still there.  When navigating the url, the ie.Document is still blank even after passing the ie.busy and ie.readystate conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is URL1, try changing that, or just putting the URL in there.

Comment: My apologies that should have read url1, in my haste to trim down the code I manually typed URL instead.  I've changed it in the question above - many thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have the object "ie" locally defined in the sub getCard and when this sub finishes,so goes the binding. Also changing from private to public internet zones can remove the binding to that object. What I rather do is use a global object appIE and then when it runs into such an error I catch the error (if TypeName(appIE) = "Object" Then FindIE) and find the object again with this sub:

```
Sub FindIE() 'Needs reference to "Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation" from VBA->Tools->References
    Dim sh
    Dim eachIE
    Dim SearchUntil
    SearchUntil = Now() + 20 / 24 / 60 / 60 'Allow to search for 20 seconds otherwise it interrupts search
    Do
      Set sh = New Shell32.Shell
      For Each eachIE In sh.Windows
        If InStr(1, eachIE.LocationURL, ServerAddress) Then
          Set appIE = eachIE
          'IE.Visible = False  'This is here because in some environments, the new process defaults to Visible.
          'Exit Do
          End If
        Next eachIE
        If TypeName(appIE) <> "Object" Then
            If InStr(1, appIE.LocationURL, ServerAddress) > 0 Or SearchUntil < Now() Then Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    Set eachIE = Nothing
    Set sh = Nothing
End Sub
```

This code contains parts of other people here from stackoverflow, but I forgot who to credit for some essential parts of the code. Sorry.